# Finding Mold After Roof Leak

Tags: mold

I have a leaking roof that I am having professionally replaced.  I had originally thought the water damage was minimal and isolated to a specific area, until a bad storm last week caused water to pour in from other areas of the house.  I plan to remove the drywall and insulation from areas that I know were affected by the leak.  I'm concerned that there may already be a mold problem, or one could develop due to the moisture.

How can I find all of the places that mold may be, or may be likely to grow after replacing my leaking roof?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, anywhere. Mold grows on walls, ceilings, windows, floors, furniture, air ducts, on clothes, etc.

My water heater had burst in my basement and had gone unnoticed for 3 days (I was away on vacation). I hired a restoration service. They found mold all the way on the opposite end of the basement. They said it was because of heavy moisture in the room.

Mold is one thing that is not worth messing with. I would hire a contractor to take an air quality test to confirm.